# Duplicate IP address in 2 mac address. Mac address Spoofing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, spoofing

Setup as below:

IP camera <-LAN cable-> CPE ))) wireless ((( AP <-LAN cable-> PoE switch <-LAN cable-> APcontroller

When the CPE connected to AP device in wireless, the APc would receive the IP address of AP but recognize the mac address of CPE device instead of mac address of AP device. This results to the AP can't communicate with APc.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this spoofing issue?

Comment: How do the AP and the CPE obtain their IP addresses? Maybe they _do_ in fact have duplicate addresses configured?

Comment: Initially, the AP [MAC: f4:xx:xx] would request ARP from the APC to get IP address (eg. 200.10.4.20). But then, the CPE device [MAC: 04:xx:xx] duplicate the IP address, which is 200.10.4.20, send the packet back to APC. As a results, the APC recognize the [MAC:04:xx] for IP address 200.10.4.20.

Comment: That doesn't sound right... ARP is usually just for determining the _current_ address. I meant something along the lines of DHCP or static IP/subnet config.

Comment: Sounds like your IP addressing scheme might not be correct - can you post a diagram with IP info?

Comment: @MarkoPolo I have just added diagram with IP info. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This chart is just plain confusing.  (De-obfuscating the MACs would make things nicer, or at least the first 6 hex digits (24 bits, half a MAC-48), which should reveal nothing except the device manufacturer.)  If AP sends an ARP WHOHAS to CPE and CPE responds, why does that response go to APC instead of AP?

All devices should have a unique MAC for any port that receives traffic (and doesn't just forward on the frame like a dumb switch).  Now, it is known that this major companies violate this rule when they deal with warranties/refurbished equipment.  However, this rule is agreed by manufacturers for when the device is initially created, so seeing the same MAC on two devices *should* be a very rare incident.

If you've actually encountered that (it has been known to happen), you should spoof (which is a fancy way of saying that you should set the device to use a custom address of your choice).  Pick something random, as it is likely unique.

Also, no two devices should have the same IP address.  Now, I know many devices do use the same IP address (especially 192.168.0.1).  There are benefits to private IPv4 addresses.  However, you don't really want to have the IP address of one device match the IP address of any other device; especially not any other device you are using.  Even if they are on different subnets.  Instead, just choose another subnet, or make your subnet larger.  And then make sure you have a different address.  This might not be strictly required in all cases, but it can simplify things by reducing the chance of accidental problems.

I'm suspecting that you may be bridging, which can allow DHCP to cross passed the boundaries of routers, because bridging can basically be a "workaround" to the protective barriers that routers provide.  That may be causing you some unexpected problems.